# Excel table function: if then or

Tags: excel, if-statement

i am crunching a large dataset. one column is "date". i want to have a column of Invoice Date. for any transaction happened in january, i want the invoice date to be Jan-31-2017...so on and so forth.

- Jan 2, 2017 (invoiceDate Jan 31, 2017)
- Jan 18, 2017 (invoiceDate Jan 31, 2017)
- Feb 5, 2017 (invoiceDate Feb 28,2017)
  ......

How to write the If function? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the EOMONTH() function

```
=EOMONTH(A2,0)
```